# Constructing the output object as single-line plain-text for each row in CSV

Tags: powershell

If the user is disabled, I want to export them as a single line. I won't export  enabled users and starting with S-1-5-21-.

e.g : CONTOSO\user11 , CONTOSO\user53 and CONTOSO\user32 are disabled.

My input file:

```
Permissions
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user23;CONTOSO\user53;S-1-5-21-609545082-2795152396-2074981628-14751
CONTOSO\user32;CONTOSO\user236
```

My desired output:

```
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user53
CONTOSO\user32
```

I have single column called 'permissions'.

Currently I am getting an console output like below. it works

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf86v.jpg

My desired output:

If the user is disabled, I want to export them as a single line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRCsl.jpg

Script :

```
$userList = (Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv).permissions -split ';'

foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $adUser = $user -replace '.*\\' | Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Property enabled   

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Identity = $user
        Status   = switch ($adUser) {
            { -not $_ } {
                'deleted'
                continue
            }
            { $_.Enabled } {
                'enabled'
                continue
            }
            default {
                'disabled'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT :

My input file:

```
Permissions
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user23;CONTOSO\user53;S-1-5-21-609545082-2795152396-2074981628-14751
CONTOSO\user32;CONTOSO\user236
```

My desired output:

```
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user53
CONTOSO\user32
```

theo script output:

```
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user53;CONTOSO\user32
```

EDIT2:

user32 ,  user45 , user200 are enabled

```
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user53
CONTOSO\user32
CONTOSO\user45;CONTOSO\user200
CONTOSO\user43;CONTOSO\user99
```

My desired output:

```
CONTOSO\user11;CONTOSO\user53
                             <-- blank line
                             <-- blank line
CONTOSO\user43;CONTOSO\user99
```

EDIT 3 :

**user01 ,  user02 : enabled
user03 : disabled**

```
Permissions
CONTOSO\user01
CONTOSO\user02
CONTOSO\user03
```

4 blank line is coming instead of 2 blank line

```
             <-- blank line
             <-- blank line
             <-- blank line
             <-- blank line
CONTOSO\user03
```

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a text file with one single line that holds the user IDs of disabled users delimited with a semi-colon (`;`)

In that case just do

```
$userList = (Import-Csv -Path D:\Test\test.csv).Permissions -split ';' |
             Where-Object { !$_.StartsWith("S-1-5-21-") }  # skip SIDs starting with "S-1-5-21-"

# look for disabled users
$result = foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $adUser = $user -replace '^.*\\' | Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adUser) {
        if (!$adUser.Enabled) { $user }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$user' could not be found in AD.."
    }
}

# output as single line in plain-text file (-PassThru will also display on screen)
$result -join ';' | Set-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\DisabledUsers.txt' -PassThru
```

---

If it is just the format of the output, then use this instead:

```
$userList = Import-Csv -Path D:\Test\test.csv
$result = foreach ($row in $userList) {
    $newRow = $row.Permissions -split ';' | ForEach-Object {
        if (!$_.StartsWith("S-1-5-21-")) {
            $adUser = $_ -replace '^.*\\' | Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($adUser) {
                if (!$adUser.Enabled) { $_ }
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "User '$_' could not be found in AD.."
            }
        }
    }
    if (@($newRow).Count) { $newRow -join ';' }
}
# output to new file
$result -join [environment]::NewLine | Set-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\DisabledUsers.txt'
```

Comment: @Arbelac Then change the title of your question too. It now clearly states: _**as single-line plain-text**_

Comment: @Arbelac Yep, that would do it

Comment: You could add `else { [Environment]::NewLine }` directly underneath `if (!$adUser.Enabled) { $_ }`

Comment: @Arbelac you keep changing your mind as to how the output should be and honestly, I have no idea why you now want it with blank lines in between. I mean.. what's the use of such output? Why not create a csv where you have the username and a field of that user being enabled or not or even not existing in AD? Why oh why combine disabled users in a single line using a semi-colon character, whilst for every enabled user you want an empty line really is beyond me..

Comment: You're right man. I am overthinking :) like you said I have figured it out another method. (enabled and disabled filtering)  thanks again